# VueJS PWA says Network Error in my small PWA. Even I can't login

Tags: reactjs, http, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli

In my PWA everything is working except POST HTTP calls. I have a login on my first screen. It says `Network Error`. But it works fine Desktop/Laptop web browser. Only found the problem on mobile app [Android]

**Note**

- I used Vue CLI for creating project.
- I also tried with React. Happened the same. I don't know what's wrong with me.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the issue

Answer (score 1):

You most likely try to connect to `localhost`. When deploying to a different device `localhost` is the actual device you are deploying and most likely you are not running a web server there.

You need to find your local machine's ip and use that as base url for HTTP calls.